# SpringBoot/JPA - erro na persistência de dados

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-jpa, persistência

Olá, pessoal.
Tenho um projeto SpringBoot e estou tentando realizar a inserção de um token no banco de dados e não estou conseguindo.
Segue minha classe:

```
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Table(name = "tbl_token")
@Entity
public class TokenInter {
    @Id()
    @Column(name = "access_token")
    private String accessToken;
    @Column(name = "expires_in")
    @JsonFormat(shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", timezone = "America/Sao_Paulo")
    private Date expiresIn;
    @Column(name = "scope")
    private String scope;
    @Column(name = "token_type")
    private String tokenType;
```

criei uma query personalizada, já definindo alguns valores, para tentar realizar a inserção.
Fiz dessa forma para realizar testes depois de não conseguir realizar pelo método .save() padrão.
Segue o método personalizado:

```
@Repository
@EnableTransactionManagement
public interface TokenInterRepository extends JpaRepository<TokenInter, String> {
    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query(value = ComandosSqlCxEmpresa.SALVAR_TOKEN, nativeQuery = true)
    void salvarToken();
}
```

Como estou acessando dois bancos de dados, criei suas respectivas classes de configuração:
Segue a classe que gerencia a classe TokenInter:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.alra.service.repository.cxempresa", 
                       entityManagerFactoryRef = "cxempresaEntityManager")
@EnableTransactionManagement
    public class CxempresaDbConfig {

        @Bean
        @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "cxempresa.datasource")
        public DataSource cxempresaDataSource() {
            return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
        }

        @Bean
        public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean cxempresaEntityManager(
                EntityManagerFactoryBuilder builder,
                @Qualifier("cxempresaDataSource") DataSource dataSource) {
            return builder.dataSource(dataSource).packages("com.alra.service.model.cxempresa").build();
        }
    }
```

Segue a classe de serviço onde chamo o realizo a chamada do método personalizado do repositório para salvar o token no banco de dados:

```
@Service
public class TokenInterService {
    @Autowired
    TokenInterRepository tokenInterRepository;
    @Autowired
    RestTemplate restTemplate;
    @Value("${inter.api.client-id}")
    private String clientId;
    @Value("${inter.api.client-secret}")
    private String clientSecret;
    private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TokenInterService.class);


    @Transactional()
    public void gerarSalvarToken() {
        logger.info("\nIniciando o processo de inserção do Token no banco de dados\n");
        tokenInterRepository.salvarToken();
        logger.info("\nFinalizando o processo de inserção do Token no banco de dados\n");
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

O problema que estou enfrentando é que os registros não são efetuados, algo ocorre que é feito o Rolling back da operação. Segue a mensagem do DEBUG:

```
11:23:04.889 [https-jsse-nio-8080-exec-6] INFO  o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/] - Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
11:23:04.889 [https-jsse-nio-8080-exec-6] INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
11:23:04.889 [https-jsse-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Detected StandardServletMultipartResolver
11:23:04.889 [https-jsse-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Detected AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver
11:23:04.889 [https-jsse-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Detected FixedThemeResolver
11:23:04.889 [https-jsse-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator@2125086c
11:23:04.889 [https-jsse-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Detected org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager@5e2525fe
11:23:04.890 [https-jsse-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - enableLoggingRequestDetails='false': request parameters and headers will be masked to prevent unsafe logging of potentially sensitive data
11:23:04.890 [https-jsse-nio-8080-exec-6] INFO  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Completed initialization in 1 ms
11:23:04.893 [https-jsse-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - POST "/auth/token", parameters={}
11:23:04.899 [https-jsse-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping - Mapped to com.alra.service.controller.TokenInterController#gerarSalvarToken()
11:23:04.899 [https-jsse-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor - Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
11:23:04.906 [https-jsse-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(1394372237<open>)] for JPA transaction
11:23:04.906 [https-jsse-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Creating new transaction with name [com.alra.service.service.cxempresa.TokenInterService.gerarSalvarToken]: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT
11:23:04.907 [https-jsse-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl - On TransactionImpl creation, JpaCompliance#isJpaTransactionComplianceEnabled == false
11:23:04.907 [https-jsse-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl - begin
11:23:04.921 [https-jsse-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@6ebeaa02]
11:23:04.921 [https-jsse-nio-8080-exec-6] INFO  c.a.s.s.cxempresa.TokenInterService - 
Iniciando o processo de inserção do Token no banco de dados

11:23:04.921 [https-jsse-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Found thread-bound EntityManager [SessionImpl(1394372237<open>)] for JPA transaction
11:23:04.921 [https-jsse-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Participating in existing transaction
11:23:04.923 [https-jsse-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.o.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils - Opening JPA EntityManager
11:23:04.935 [https-jsse-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG org.hibernate.orm.query.plan.cache - Creating and caching NativeQuery ParameterInterpretation - ParameterInterpretationImpl (    INSERT INTO tbl_token(
        access_token, expires_in, scope, token_type)
        VALUES ('ec0425bd-96fd-4d3a-997f-40a375e3eb38', '2023-08-22 15:28:58', 'boleto-cobranca.read boleto-cobranca.write', 'Bearer');
) : {
}
11:23:04.939 [https-jsse-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Participating transaction failed - marking existing transaction as rollback-only
11:23:04.939 [https-jsse-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Setting JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(1394372237<open>)] rollback-only
11:23:04.939 [https-jsse-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.h.r.t.b.j.i.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl - JDBC transaction marked for rollback-only (exception provided for stack trace)
java.lang.Exception: exception just for purpose of providing stack trace
    at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.markRollbackOnly(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:310)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.markRollbackOnly(TransactionImpl.java:203)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.setRollbackOnly(TransactionImpl.java:224)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager$JpaTransactionObject.setRollbackOnly(JpaTransactionManager.java:711)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doSetRollbackOnly(JpaTransactionManager.java:610)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processRollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:844)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.rollback(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:809)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.completeTransactionAfterThrowing(TransactionAspectSupport.java:678)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:395)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:135)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:244)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy116.salvarToken(Unknown Source)
    at com.alra.service.service.cxempresa.TokenInterService.gerarSalvarToken(TokenInterService.java:45)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:196)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:756)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:391)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:184)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:756)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
    at com.alra.service.service.cxempresa.TokenInterService$$SpringCGLIB$$0.gerarSalvarToken(<generated>)
    at com.alra.service.controller.TokenInterController.gerarSalvarToken(TokenInterController.java:21)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:118)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:884)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:797)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1081)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:974)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1011)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:914)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:590)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:885)
    at jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:658)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:174)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:149)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:482)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:115)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:341)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:391)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:894)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1740)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589)
11:23:04.941 [https-jsse-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Initiating transaction rollback
11:23:04.941 [https-jsse-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Rolling back JPA transaction on EntityManager [SessionImpl(1394372237<open>)]
11:23:04.941 [https-jsse-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl - rolling back
11:23:04.942 [https-jsse-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager - Not closing pre-bound JPA EntityManager after transaction
11:23:04.948 [https-jsse-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor - Using 'text/plain', given [*/*] and supported [text/plain, */*, application/json, application/*+json]
11:23:04.949 [https-jsse-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor - Writing ["Erro ao salvar token: Executing an update/delete query"]
11:23:04.952 [https-jsse-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor - Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
11:23:04.952 [https-jsse-nio-8080-exec-6] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Completed 500 INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR
```

Quando utilizo o mesmo comando SQL direto no Postgres, a execução é concluída com sucesso e as informações são salvas no banco de dados.
Quando executo por meio do meu projeto, o retorno sempre é : "Executing an update/delete query".
Conseguem me ajudar a resolver este problema?

Muito obrigado.